# Open remote stream on bucket S3 amazon in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my code:

```
    $client = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => $region,
        'credentials' => ['key' => $key, 'secret'  => $secret]
    ]);

    $client->registerStreamWrapper();

    $filename = md5(gethostname()) .'_'. basename($file);

    $bucketStream = fopen("s3://{$bucket}/{$filename}", 'w+');
```

If I list my buckets, I get a list of them, so it is not a connection problem. My issue that I can't upload any files to S3. and this: `$bucketStream` is `false`.

Comment: Is there a need to use a stream?

Comment: yeah. And this worked . And all of the sudden 3-4 days from now , doens;t work anymore

Answer (score 0):

> You can upload larger files by streaming data using fopen() and a "w",
>   "x", or "a" stream access mode. The Amazon S3 stream wrapper does not
>   support simultaneous read and write streams (e.g. "r+", "w+", etc).
>   This is because the HTTP protocol does not allow simultaneous reading
>   and writing.

try to change the `w+` to `w`

Reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html

Comment: It's still false :(

Comment: did you try to `var_dump($stream)` ? and check you get error? also use `error_last_get()` to catch last error